# Session variable: save an auto increment from a sql field next a insertion

Tags: php, sql, select, session-variables, auto-increment

I want to save in a session variable on php  an auto increment value field from one SQL table, just next to do the insert on that table. Why it appears empty? What should I do?

Because I check my sql statement on the database and everything is correct, all of that and have values.

```
$usersetdataregister="INSERT INTO `questionnaire`.`tbluserset`(`UserIDFKPK`, `QuestionSetIDFKPK`) VALUES ('$UserId','0')"; 

mysql_query($usersetdataregister);

$query_usersetID= "SELECT tbluserset.UserSetIDPK 
                   FROM tbluserset 
                   INNER JOIN (SELECT US.UserIDFKPK, MAX(US.Timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp
                               FROM tbluserset AS US
                               WHERE US.UserIDFKPK ='$UserId' 
                               GROUP BY US.UserIDFKPK) AS USL ON tbluserset.UserIDFKPK = USL.UserIDFKPK AND tbluserset.Timestamp = USL.MaxTimestamp";

 $row_UserSetIDPK = mysql_query($query_usersetID);

 $UserSetID= $row_UserSetIDPK['UserSetIDPK'];
 $_SESSION['UserSetIDPK']= $UserSetID;
```

Next to do this i want use the value on a query statement and UserSetIDPK appears empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to start your session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSIONS['UserSetIDPK'] = $UserSetID;
```

You should also check what $row_UserSetIDPK is returning. If it's empty then there is something wrong with your query, or he can't find any results in your database.

If it's not empty, you should see if $row_UserSetIDPK['UserSetIDPK'] is the right way to get your value. 
to debug try this:

```
var_dump($row_UserSetIDPK);die();
```

Hope this helps a bit, 'cause your post is quite a mess! :-)

Comment: I don't forget that , in fact your second line was there.I said that i check my queries and all works correct on SQL. I only post the part of the code about how im saving the value on my session variable because is there where is the problem :) .But thanks for your atencion Bananam00n :)

Comment: and you did start the session somewhere?

Comment: yes , at the begining of course. It's really strange because if i do that with static values (if i write directly values there on queries ) everything work , the problem is why the session value don't save the auto increment from the field. And that Select works and is NOT empty. But don't save it.

Comment: I just find the error , the problem was that i wasnt doing mysql_feltch_array()->    $query_usersetID= "SELECT tbluserset.UserSetIDPK 
                     FROM tbluserset 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT US.UserIDFKPK, MAX(US.Timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp
                    FROM tbluserset AS US
           WHERE US.UserIDFKPK ='".$UserId."' 
           GROUP BY US.UserIDFKPK) AS USL ON tbluserset.UserIDFKPK = USL.UserIDFKPK AND tbluserset.Timestamp = USL.MaxTimestamp";
           
  $setquery_UserSetIDPK = mysql_query($query_usersetID);
   $row_UserSetIDPK=mysql_fetch_array ($setquery_UserSetIDPK);